# kendo dropdownlist setting value on datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

im having the same problem as this one:

[Setting default value of a dropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385806/setting-default-value-of-a-dropdownlist)

i have dropdownlist on my grid but it does not save the selected value into the data source.

Unlike the textbox where i can do it using

**container.find("input[name=Code]").val(d.Code).change();**

this dont work on dropdownlists, and if i use .select(d.Code) it does select the value on dropdown but does not save it into datasource.

thanks in advance

Comment: post the grid markup..

Comment: i dont have any markup, only js

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: nevermind, i got a solution using: var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var selection = grid.select(); //single selection
var rowData = grid.dataItem(selection); rowData.Code = d.Code.